# Change the font of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

[image: UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItem]

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` in my `UIToolbar` titled **Done**. Now I want to change the font from the default to **"Trebuchet MS"** with Bold. How can I do that?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Because UIBarButtonItem inherits from UIBarItem, you can try

```
- (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
                  forState:(UIControlState)state
```

but this is for iOS5 only. For iOS 3/4, you will have to use a custom view.

Answer (score 229):

To be precise, this can be done as below

```
[buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0], NSFontAttributeName,
    [UIColor greenColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
    nil] 
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or with object literal syntax:

```
[buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{
     NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0],
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]
} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For convenience, here's the Swift implementation:

```
buttonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.regularPoppinsFont(withSize: 26),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white],
                                     for: .normal)
```

Comment: NSFontAttributeName should be used instead UITextAttributeFont, and NSForegroundColorAttributeName should be instead of UITextAttributeTextColor when developing for IOS7.

Answer (score 134):

For those interested in using `UIAppearance` to style their `UIBarButtonItem`'s fonts throughout the app, it can be accomplished using this line of code:

**Objective C:**

```
NSDictionary *barButtonAppearanceDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift 2.3:**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
[
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white
],
for: .normal)
```

**Swift 3**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
[
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
], for: .normal)
```

**Swift 4**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
[
    NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
], for: .normal)
```

Or for a single UIBarButtonItem (not for all app wide), if you have a custom font for one button in particular:

**Swift 3**

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButton()
barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 26)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
], for: .normal)
barButtonItem.title = "\u{f02a}"
```

**Swift 4**

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButton()
barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
    NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 26)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
], for: .normal)
barButtonItem.title = "\u{f02a}"
```

Of course, you can change the font & size to whatever you'd like. I prefer to put this code in the `AppDelegate.m` file in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` section.

Available attributes (just add them to the `NSDictionary`):

- `NSFontAttributeName`: Change font with a `UIFont`
- `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`: Change color with a `UIColor`
- `NSShadow`: Add a drop shadow (see [`NSShadow` class reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/)

(Updated for iOS7+)

Comment: The UITextAttribute.. keys are deprecated as of iOS7. Use NSFontAttribute... and NSForeground... etc instead.

Comment: I have updated for the deprecations introduced in iOS7.  Thanks for the heads up, @EmmanuelAy!

Comment: Fantastic! My app is looking beautiful now (well, in my own way that is!! :P) Thank you

Comment: Swift 5: `NSAttributedStringKey` is renamed to `NSAttributedString.Key`

Answer (score 21):

In Swift you would do this as followed:

```
backButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 26)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()],
    forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Don't forget the exclamation mark (!) after the font. The error message: "'_' is not convertible to 'String'" is not really helpful.

Answer (score 17):

These are great answers above. Just updating for iOS7:

```
NSDictionary *barButtonAppearanceDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:18.0] , NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 16):

**Swift3**

```
  buttonName.setAttributedTitle([
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.black],
                                     forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**swift**

```
   barbutton.setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(),NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()],
        forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Objective-C**

```
     [ barbutton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0], NSFontAttributeName,
        [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIColor blackColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,
        nil]
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 11):

Swift 5 Implementation

```
rightButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 26.0)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green],
        for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 8):

To do this for some `UIBarButtonItems` but not all I recommend the following approach.

1. Create a `UIBarButtonItem` subclass. Don't add anything to it - you will only use it as a custom class in the storyboard and for its appearance proxy...
2. In your storyboard, change the custom class for all desired `UIBarButtonItems` to your subclass
3. In your AppDelegate import your `UIBarButtonItem` subclass and add the following line to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

In my case I subclassed `UIBarButtonItem` for the sole purpose of bolding the text:

```
[[BoldBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
    [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0], NSFontAttributeName,nil] 
                                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 8):

In **Swift 4**, you can change the font and colour of `UIBarButtonItem` by adding the following code.

```
addTodoBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes(
        [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 17)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
        ], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the right way:
declare your barButtonItem (in this case rightBarButtonItem) and add it setTitleTextAttributes.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Go!", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourFuncDestination))
```

after you can add title attributes

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold), .foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

you can change the size, the weight (.bold, .heavy, .regular etc.) and the color how you prefer...
Hope this help :)

Answer (score 2):

swift 3

```
barButtonName.setTitleTextAttributes( [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Throughout App:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 15) {
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:TOOLBAR_TITLE_COLOR], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButton` haven't property related to change the font. But you can create a button with custom font and then add into UIBarButton. It May be solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to support iOS4 and earlier, your best bet is to create a bar button using the `initWithCustomView:` method and supply your own view which could be something like a UIButton where you can easily customise the font.

You can also drag a UIButton onto a toolbar or navigation bar in Interface Builder if you want to create the button with drag-and-drop instead of programmatically.

Unfortunately this means creating the button background image yourself. There's no way to customise the font of a standard UIBarButtonItem prior to iOS5.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `UIView` programmatically:

```
UIView *buttonItemView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
```

Then add images, labels or whatever you like to your custom view:

```
[buttonItemView addSubview:customImage];

[buttonItemView addSubview:customLabel];

...
```

Now put it in your `UIBarButtomItem`.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonItemView];
```

And finally add barButtonItem to you navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

For completion I would like to add this method, still used in Objective-C in 2019. :)

```
_titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_titleLabel.text = _titleBarButtonItem.title;
_titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
_titleLabel.font = [UtilityMethods appFontProDisplayBold:26.0];

[_titleLabel sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *titleLabelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_titleLabel];
```