# LeftBarButtonItem not working on iOS7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, slidingmenu

I am using [this API](https://github.com/andreamazz/SlideOutNavigation) in my application. The sample app given is working fine for both iOS7 and 6. After integrating it into my app Tap Gesture is not working on `UILeftBarButtonItem` in iOS 7, but working in iOS 6. Please see the screen shot below:

[image]

Both `UIRightBarButtonItems` are working fine and their action is getting executed but the left button is not working in iOS7

I have wasted several hours but couldn't figure out why it is not working only in iOS7. I found this thread on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054625/changing-back-button-in-ios-7-disables-swipe-to-navigate-back) but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late to answer but you made a serious mistake relying on subview index.

My approach for such a case would be

1. Make an IBOutlet of UIButton and add it to navigation bar.
2. When it comes to enable to disable I would use the outlet of button.

Hope that would help anybody else facing this problem.

Comment: Undoubtedly this would be the better approach. I was so stupid I couldn't get that idea :(

Comment: Using IBOutlets will save your life from different version changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to answer my question
The problem was that I was disabling the refresh button on top right corner of the `Navigation Bar` on start of the method it triggers and reenabling it later on the basis of subview index but some strange reason it was disabling my leftbar button but in iOs6 it was disabling the Refresh button. There is some problem with the Subview indexing in iOS7.0