# iOS 7 InteractivePopGesture with full screen UICollectionView

Tags: ios, scroll, ios7, uicollectionview

My app has a full-screen UICollectionView with a horizontal scroll direction. When I swipe from the edge, intending for the NavigationController to pick up the InteractivePopGesture, the CollectionView interprets it as a horizontal scroll.

Is there any way to use the new InteractivePopGesture with a full screen scrollable view?

Edit: The comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076323/683114) describe the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this problem on a different question. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23812297/1639049) works for you.