# How to change the image of back button on the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationbar

In a storyboard, I create a navigation bar by using "Embed in".

I'm trying to replace the original image of back button, which is like this

[image]

by my back button image, which is

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controllers viewDidLoad method add following code..

```
UIImage *leftbuttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename"];
        UIButton *leftbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [leftbutton setImage:leftbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        leftbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);
        [leftbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLeftMenuPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *customBarleftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftbutton];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarleftItem;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. In line "[leftbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLeftMenuPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];", xcode says showLeftMenuPressed is not declared. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: sorry to not mention that.. replace showLeftMenuPressed: method by your method which you want to call on back button click.

Comment: Notice that if you replace your back button, then the swipe gesture to go back in iOS 7 stops working. Some solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054625/changing-back-button-in-ios-7-disables-swipe-to-navigate-back

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackBtn.png"]  ;  
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 30);  
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;  
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

and declare goback:

```
- (void)goback
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)setUpNAvigationBackBarButton
{

    UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"];
    CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);
    UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(YourMethod which you wanna call on back button
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:mailbutton animated:YES];
}
```

just call this function in your viewdidLoad.
I have used same this function in ma code. working fine.. you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version :-

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "HomeLeft@2x")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "HomeLeft@2x")
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

put this on viewDidLoad( )