# UINavigationContoller interactivePopGestureRecognizer inactive when navigation bar is hidden

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller which is nested within a `UINavigationController`.

I have implemented the iOS 7 interactivePopGestureRecognizer to enable the user to gesture to pop a VC off the stack.

Within the VC i have a scrollview and whilst the user is not at the top of the scrollview I hide all the chrome (Navigation bar and status bar) to place focus on the content.

However with the navigation bar hidden, the interactivePopGestureRecognizer is not working.

I have tried enabling it after it has disappeared and verified it is not nil, however it still doesn't work.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Set your UIViewController subclass as the gestureRecognizer's delegate:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks, in fact setting it to nil also works. I wonder if this is a bug?

Comment: There will be a bug if set self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate to self or nil: Swipe from the edge of the screen, and tap something to push a view controller into the navigation controller quickly, then -- 1. The current view controller does not respond any touch event; 2. The new view contrller will not be shown; 3. Swipe from the edge of the screen again, the new view contrller will be shown; 4. Call popViewControllerAnimated: with the animated parameter set to NO (tap the custom back button), crash!

Comment: It looks like *just* setting the delegate isn't enough, see the crash report by @iwill. The workaround we found was to store the original delegate, e.g. in `viewDidLoad`, set yourself as the new one in `viewDidAppear:` and then reset it again to the original one in `viewDidDisappear:`. Kinda strange, but works.

Comment: @Dennis having the same problem, but I tried your solution, doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I would not recommend this solution. It resulted in several bugs when presenting/popping view controllers.

Comment: You should set it in viewDidAppear
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}

Comment: If you want to use further `interactivePop` in your navigation stack you have to save delegate object before changing `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` and restore the initial value when `UIViewController` disappears.

Comment: @iwill did you ever figure out how to do this right? Im experiencing the same exact issue you mentioned/

Comment: @ArieLitovsky what would you suggest for this then?

Comment: @user7097242 I posted an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672693/456536

Answer (score 16):

Simple solution

Just set the hidden property of the navigation bar not through navigation controller

Just use these two lines

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 7):

I used this.
`self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;`

also in my UINavigationController class to disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer during transitions.

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
              animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        // disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer in the rootViewController of navigationController
        if ([[navigationController.viewControllers firstObject] isEqual:viewController]) {
            navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        } else {
            // enable interactivePopGestureRecognizer
            navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

the reason of disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer in rootViewController is:when swipe from edge in rootViewController and then tap something to push in next viewController, the UI won't accept any touches now.Press home button to put app in background , and then tap it to enter foreground...

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to work for me. I followed Keithl's blog post. Neither did that work.

I ultimately settled with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. It seems to do what it says.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:)];
[gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `UIEdgePanGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Not an ideal solution but it'll do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two lines to `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` worked for me.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

And dont forget to call `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` to `.h` file.