# Swipe to go back is disabled if the navigation bar is hidden

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, gesture-recognition

My iOS 7 app uses `UINavigationController` with a hidden navigation bar. The top of my main screen includes a custom tab bar. I want to rely exclusively on the swipe to go back gesture, or the navigation buttons in the tab bar, without displaying the navigation bar and its back button.

What I'm observing is that setting `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES` hides the navigation bar and disables the gesture recognizer. Swiping left to right from the screen edge does nothing when I've descended a level in the navigation controller.

With this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate);
}
```

I get:

> 2013-12-09 22:18:32.082 Redacted[496:60b]
>   ;
>   target= <(action=handleNavigationTransition:,
>   target=<_UINavigationInteractiveTransition 0x146612f0>)>>
>
> 2013-12-09 22:18:36.795 Redacted[496:60b]
>   <_UINavigationInteractiveTransition: 0x146612f0>

...which is the same regardless if I'm setting navigationBarHidden to `YES` or `NO`. So, the gesture recognizer, and its delegate, are both valid.

So why is this gesture recognizer not working when the navigation bar is hidden, and how do I fix that?

This is an iOS 7 app for iPhone/iPod touch screens.

Comment: Please try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054625/changing-back-button-in-ios-7-disables-swipe-to-navigate-back

Comment: Yes, that worked. This can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I have the same problem. May I know which answer on that solution worked? I tried the accepted answer and it did not work. 
That question seems to be about a back button image, while my problem is with the hidden navbar.

Comment: Looking at this again, I believe I implemented the accepted answer on that other question. However, I later changed the user interface and no longer depend on this.