# Setting uinavigationitem's back button not working

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uinavigationitem

After reading a bunch of similar questions on SO I've found out that in order to use a custom back button view I should be setting the nav controller's nav bar's nav item's left button item to a custom view, but no matter what I do I'm getting stuck with the default. I've tried setting this both inside the view controller I want to navigate back from, as well as the one I'm navigating back to, to no avail. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
- (void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
     UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn"]]];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you are not adding you navigationController to any superview

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The nav controller is presented modally from another view controller.

Comment: try do the same but in `viewWill/DidAppear`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing you’re doing wrong is using the bar button item on the navigation controller instead of on your view controller. To quote Apple’s [View Controller Catalog for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW37):

> In a navigation interface, each *content* view controller in the navigation stack provides a navigation item as the value of its navigationItem property.

Emphasis mine; the content view controller is your custom view controller. Try this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

You need to do this in all your view controllers that should have the custom button, so I recommend creating your own base view controller class that subclasses `UIViewController` and implements custom back buttons, and use this base view controller as the parent of your other view controllers.

You’re hiding the navigation bar, which probably isn’t a good idea if you want it to show a custom back button.

By replacing the standard back button, you lose its tap behaviour. Use a `UIButton` in the bar button item’s custom view instead of a `UIImageView`.

Also, it would be more conventional to put this setup code in `viewDidLoad` rather than `loadView`.

So I would do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton sizeToFit];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popNavigationController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
}

- (void)popNavigationController:(id)sender
{
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note that if you use a custom back button, the swipe-from-the-edge-of-the-screen-to-go-back gesture will not work. See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054625/changing-back-button-in-ios-7-disables-swipe-to-navigate-back) for a couple of potential solutions, but it’s fiddly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help. Do you know of a good cheat sheet to help reason about when setup code should be called (e.g., in viewdidload, viewwillappear, etc.)?

Comment: I don’t know of a cheat sheet. `loadView` should create the main view and set it to the view controller’s `view` property, and is typically not overridden and does not call `super` (because the view can only be created once). `viewDidLoad` does any other setup that needs to happen once when the view loads, and should call `super`.