# Same Viewcontroller pops multiple times

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

**Required:**

I want to enable iOS7 swipe to back feature with custom navigation back button item.

**Current Implementation:**

After researching a lot, I found the following solution to be best:

1. Set the delegate of the gesture recognizer as follows

   ```
   self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
   ```
2. This, creates a lot of bugs as mentioned in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672693/2954866). To avoid that, subclassing the UINavigationController seems to be the only feasible option. I did that as mentioned in this [blog](http://keighl.com/post/ios7-interactive-pop-gesture-custom-back-button/) by [Keighl](http://keighl.com/post/ios7-interactive-pop-gesture-custom-back-button/).

**Problem:**

Basic swipe to back feature is working, but the strange thing is that, sometimes, the same `viewController` that is being dismissed, appears again after the pop action is completed.

i.e. suppose the navigation stack looks like **A -> B**. Popping **B** will again bring up **B**. This keeps on happening until eventually the viewController **B** actually gets dismissed and **A** appears.

This happens to all views in all viewController objects and not just to a specific one. 
Also, I have ensured that the `push` method is called only once at all places.

I also tried logging the navigation stack at each point, but there is only one instance of each `viewController`.

**Point to note:**

I need to disable the swipe feature in certain views. I did this by writing the code to `disable` and `enable` the swipe gesture in `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` respectively.

Please provide your valuable suggestions or a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer actually work for you?

Comment: Haven't tried out after that. But now, I think the same can be achieved using View Controller Transitioning API.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: You should add a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to your view controller if you want to add a pop gesture where none exists. Modifying the existing `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is probably not the right approach. Do this:

```
[self addGestureRecognizer:({
    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *gesture =
        [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pop)];
    gesture;
})];
```

and

```
-(void)pop {
    // pop your view controller here
}
```

**Long answer**: Forcing the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` **is** what breaks your code.

If you need to cast *self* as such:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate =
    (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
```

...it is because `self` is not a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. The following should compile, link, build and run or you are setting yourself up for trouble:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Note that being a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` specifically allows you to tweak a gesture's behavior at runtime, assuming you are implementing one of the following **and** ensuring that the tweak applies to **a gesture you own**:

1. `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`
2. `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`
3. `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`
4. `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:`
5. `gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:`

By constantly changing the *delegate* of that `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` you did not create, all you are doing is **preventing the iOS behavior** to take place.

**From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer)**

*UINavigationController -interactivePopGestureRecognizer*

*The gesture recognizer responsible for popping the top view controller off the navigation stack. (read-only)*

**In plain English**: Use this value is you need to combine that gesture with your own gesture. But you are not supposed to modify its behavior:

*...You can use this property to retrieve the gesture recognizer and tie it to the behavior of other gesture recognizers in your user interface...*

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the detailed answer. Did you mean that it will work if I remove the cast to self?

Comment: Not quite. I believe you should not set `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` at all. This going in the wrong direction. What is **not** working when you remove that line entirely?

Comment: okay. See, I have custom left bar button items in my app. When I use them the default swipe gesture feature is gone. According to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19076323/2954866), setting the delegate to self would enable it.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion to enable swipe feature with custom leftBarButton items?

Comment: es. You should add a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. I updated the answer.

Comment: This approach was what I thought of first but I need to do this for all screens in an already existing project. That is why I went for changing the delegate. Now I think I am left with no choice but to  create a base class first, and then add the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` in that class. Will accept your answer after I try it.

Comment: Super. Yes, code sweep is actually a good option. Consider a category instead of a subclass, or a 1 method utility. I will delete most comments after that, to reduce noise.