# Setting up iOS Navigation Elements

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am having difficulty figuring out how to set up my UINavigationController to get the result I want.  Most succinctly, I want to mimic the navigation of the app BriefMe.

Specifically, I want:

- a main view (*v#1*) that segues to a new view controller (*v#2*) with an embedded UIWebView
- to permanently hide/disable the navigation bar and toolbar on v#1, but I do want a toolbar on v#2 (ideally which shows/hides on swipe -- I figure this can be solved with a UIGestureRecognizer if not through the NavController's hide on swipe/tap property)
- v#2 to segue back to v#1 on a swipe from the left edge of the screen, just like the default NavController behavior, shown here.

[image]

I've run into two problems with my attempt to set this up:

1. I can't permanently hide the navigation/toolbar on v#1 while leaving v#1+#2 embedded in a NavController.  Without the NavController, I don't retain the swipe-to-segue functionality when v#2 is at the top of the stack
2. Allowing the WebView to scroll disables/'intercepts' the swipe-to-segue functionality.  My only thought is to disable interaction with the WebView, place the WebView in a ScrollView, and allow only vertical scrolling on the ScrollView.  Will this allow the swipe-to-segue to work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly:

1. We’re still popping a controller from the stack during the transition. We just add the navigation bar as a subview of the controller’s view at the top of the stack and then set up the back event manually.
2. We ended up using a version of the answer specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20099321/1480438). We added an extra invisible thin column overlaying the left side of the webview because some webviews were still giving us trouble.

Hope that helps!