# Replace back button but keeping swipe to navigate back

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

First of all, I have noticed that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054625/changing-back-button-in-ios-7-disables-swipe-to-navigate-back/20330647#20330647). However, I would like to ask about the solution in Swift. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
}
```

I want to replace the back button but keeping the swipe for user to navigate back. However, this disables the swipe. I cannot get the accepted answer and the suggested answer in the link above to work. Here is what I tried to translated into Swift.

```
let appearanceNavigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
appearanceNavigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back")
appearanceNavigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back")
appearanceNavigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

I am using Xcode 8.0 beta, Swift 2.3 and testing in iOS 10.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this property: `interactivePopGestureRecognizer `

Comment: @Siam Setting `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = true` do nothing. Reassigning `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` lead to a lot of issues. (From the suggested answer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I used this and it worked:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: This works. Would you mind to explain the reason(s) behind?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not complete. If you have a storyboard segue configured and you attempt a "swipe back" gesture on the first view controller you may be unable to trigger the segue.

The best solution which takes all edge cases into the account is:

```
class QFNavigationController:UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        delegate = self
    }

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    }

    // IMPORTANT: without this if you attempt swipe on
    // first view controller you may be unable to push the next one
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }

}
```

Now just use `QFNavigationController` whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting delegate to `nil` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38180152/2982854) causes some nasty bugs in iOS 11, for example [this one](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5020321891483648)

But the idea of stubbing the delegate is good in general. For example, you can write the following code

```
final class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    private var customDelegate: InteractivePopGestureRecognizerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customDelegate = InteractivePopGestureRecognizerDelegate(
            originalDelegate: interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate,
            navigationController: self
        ) 
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = customDelegate
    }
}
```

Then you can use your custom delegate to fix the root cause of the problem

```
final class InteractivePopGestureRecognizerDelegate:
    NSObject,
    UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    private weak var originalDelegate: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?
    private weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    init(
        originalDelegate: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?,
        navigationController: UINavigationController)
    {
        self.originalDelegate = originalDelegate
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(
        _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldReceive touch: UITouch)
        -> Bool
    {
        if let originalDelegate = originalDelegate,
            let result = originalDelegate.gestureRecognizer?(
                gestureRecognizer,
                shouldReceive: touch)
        {
            if !result {
                // Your interactive pop gesture got cancelled here

                // Perform sanity check of pop possibility
                if (navigationController?.viewControllers.count ?? 0) < 2 {
                    return result
                }

                if navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden == true {
                    // Return true here if you want to swipe even without navigation bar
                    return result
                }

                // Enable pop gesture
                return true
            }
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    ...
    // Proxy all other `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods to the originalDelegate here
    ...
}
```

Of course this is a bit tricky and may not work in the future (like every other hack)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you probably don't need a solution to this problem anymore as 3 years have passed:) But maybe this will help someone else to fix this problem. It's actually pretty simple: you just need to configure the back button, which will be presented on a second view controller from first view controller. Here's an example:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill"), style: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
  }

  func presentSecondViewController() {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
  }
}
```

Configuring FirstViewController this way will allow you to display custom back button on the SecondViewController and also keep swipe-back gesture.